# Media query in Wordpress child theme not working

Tags: css, wordpress, media-queries

I have created a child theme for the Wordpress TwentyThirteen theme. I wish to hide the banner for mobile devices.

This is what I have tried for the iPhone 4s (the device I'm testing on):

```
/* style.css */

...

@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) {
    .home-link {
        display: none !important;
    }
}
```

This meta tag is generated by the parent theme:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

and

`.home-link` is the class of the anchor that wraps the banner I wish to hide.

Why is this not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was to copy the format of the media query from the parent theme:

```
@media (max-width: 643px) {
    .home-link {
        display: none !important;
    }   
}
```

I assume that the media query I had used originally (in my question) is dominated by this one (?).